# Remote IE click has no effect

Tags: java, selenium

Nothing happens after clicking on the web element. I have even print the statement after the click operation which is executed correctly but after that is is failing as click operation is not changing the object state.

Steps to reproduce -

1. create a selenium script to load google home page.
2. click on the I'm feeling Lucky button`enter code here.
3. it should load the doodle page.

When I run this script on my local machine, it worked fine. Now i have created an executable jar file using maven and eclipse to run my test suit and downloaded this jar on my remote desktop machine on server with all the necessary dependent files.

When I run the test using CMD `java -jar "test-suit.jar"`.

It is opening IE browser successfully and load the url . It is clicking on I'm feeling lucky but it does not load doodle page after click and test fails . no error is given just i got this log:

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protoc
    ol.RequestAddCookies).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more in
    fo.
    Sep 20, 2018 7:28:39 AM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager getDriversFrom
    Xml
    INFO: Reading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek IEDriverS
    erver
    Sep 20, 2018 7:28:40 AM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager getLatest
    INFO: Latest version of IEDriverServer is 3.14
    Sep 20, 2018 7:28:40 AM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader checkBinary
    INFO: Using binary driver previously downloaded
    Sep 20, 2018 7:28:40 AM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager exportDriver
    INFO: Exporting webdriver.ie.driver as C:\Users\debolin.dhar.m2\repository\webd
    river\IEDriverServer\Win32\3.14\IEDriverServer.exe
    null
    true
    null
    false
    Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
    3.14.0.0
    Listening on port 24032
    Only local connections are allowed
    Sep 20, 2018 7:28:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSessi
    on
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    true
    false
    clicked on I'm feeling lucky
    doodle Page doesn't exist

    ===============================================
    Suite
    Total tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
```

I don't understand what could be the error. Whether it is not clicking and not throwing any error also or I need to take certain additional settings to be set on my server machine or change in my script to get it work.

Comment: Show the code, not the log.